# How to connect an express JS app to github API

Tags: javascript, express

I recently started using expressJS for the first time.  I am having trouble connecting it to the github API so I can run commands to find comments and things like that on a given repo.

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have tried using: https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github but I am not sure how to integrate this API with expressJS app

Here is an example of what I have so far that is not working correctly:

```
var GitHubApi = require("github");

var github = new GitHubApi({
    // required
    version: "3.0.0",
    // optional
    debug: true,
    protocol: "https",
    host: "github.com",
    pathPrefix: "/joyent/node", // for some GHEs
    timeout: 5000
});
github.gitdata.getCommit({
    // optional:
    // headers: {
    //     "cookie": "blahblah"
    // },
    user: "bnoordhuis",
    repo: "/commit",
    sha: "c30cc4e3a5ead3ca5b48e8eec445740775888ed8"
}, function(err, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
});
```

Comment: I have tired using https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github but i am not sure how it integrates with expressJS app.

Comment: It doesn't integrate with ExpressJS.  You need to write your own code in an Express route handler to call their functions.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Specifically the above code is giving me the error null bnoordhuis.  I am trying to use expressjs app to get commit data from git hub.  So i just picked a random github repo and picked a random person using that repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library that wraps the Github API. For example, `node-github` (100% covered).

- Installation: `npm install github`
- Documentation: https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github

Comment: I came across this myself.  The only problem is that the documentation doesn't include integration with expressJS, only how to use the api in javascript.  I am not sure how the expressJS app and the API interact.  Maybe I am over thinking this...

Comment: You can use any library with Express.js. There's absolutely no problem. Express allows you a lot of freedom about your code structure, third-party libraries, etc.

Comment: Awesome!  Would you happen to have an example of this?